# html form is connected to mysql, but it isn't submitting any data nor it is creating empty rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

Update Oct 11 2020

I tried this code:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sip-krl");
 
// Check connection
if($connect === false){
    die("ERROR: Koneksi gagal " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id_jenisPembayaran = $_POST['id_jenisPembayaran'];
$nama_jenisPembayaran = $_POST['nama_jenisPembayaran'];
 
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO jenispembayaran (id_jenisPembayaran, nama_jenisPembayaran) VALUES ('$id_jenisPembayaran', '$nama_jenisPembayaran')";
if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
    echo "Data berhasil dimasukkan";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Data gagal masuk ke basis data $sql. " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 
// Close connection
$connect->close();

header("location:/skripsi-manual/data-jenisPembayaran.php");
?>
```

It works perfectly. However, this also makes my program vulnerable to SQL Injection.

I'm stumped as why this (the code above) works but the code below gets me nowhere?

Could anyone show me the why?
Thanks in advance.

---

I'm making a form to input type of payment data to my database. The codes are following:

**.php file = input-jenisPembayaran.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sip-krl";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

$id_jenisPembayaran = mysqli_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['id_jenisPembayaran']);
$nama_jenisPembayaran = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nama_jenisPembayaran']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO jenispembayaran (id_jenisPembayaran, nama_jenisPembayaran);
VALUES (?,?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    echo "Error.";
} else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $id_jenisPembayaran, $nama_jenisPembayaran);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

header("location:/skripsi-manual/jenispembayaran.php?tambah-data=success");

$conn->close();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

**Form: jenispembayaran.php**

```
<div class="content">
        <form action="./assets/php/input-jenisPembayaran.php" method="POST">
           <article class="card">
                <h4> Masukkan Jenis Pembayaran </h4>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="id_jenisPembayaran">Kode Jenis Pembayaran:</label>
                <input type="text" name="id_jenisPembayaran" id="id_jenisPembayaran">
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="nama_jenisPembayaran">Nama Jenis Pembayaran:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama_jenisPembayaran" id="nama_jenisPembayaran">
                <br>
                <br>
                <button input type="submit" value="submit">Masukkan</button>
            </article>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Database structure:**

> dbName: sip-krl =>
> table: jenispembayaran =>
> tableRows: id_jenisPembayaran(int), nama_jenisPembayaran(varchar)

"input-jenisPembayaran.php" manages to connect my form to the database. But it fails to insert the data I typed in.

Could anyone show me where my code went wrong and show me how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_escape_string()`

Comment: You cannot use headers after you've echoed something. I think you need to do some debugging first. [Switch on error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and check for MySQL errors.

Comment: @Dharman, Okay. I'll scrap that line.

Comment: @Dharman: I already deleted the line (and saved the file and reloaded it). Still, it didn't save any data.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: I've tried it. But it didn't display any error. It was as if I didn't put the syntax at all. (Every time. Except for that time I tried putting it on top of my form.php file (above the <!Doctype HTML>), it printed the syntax on the top left of my page.)

Comment: `<button input type="submit" value="submit">` < that button won't work; remove the `input`.

Comment: *"it printed the syntax on the top left of my page"* - What do you mean by that, that it prints code?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: I mean, the code is written on the top left of my page. Literally, with the semicolon. 
I've deleted the 'input' and still, nothing changed.

Comment: Seems to me that you're not running this off a web server or you're using `file:///` instead of using an HTTP prototocol, am I correct on this?

Comment: Are you able to detect whether the `INSERT` query did execute or not? I have this habit of checking by deliberately using a non-existent table in my query to see if it return any error or not. I mean, try changing the table name in your insert query to something like `INSERT INTO jenispembayaranxxxx .... ` and see if it return table not exists error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: I'm running this with xampp (localhost/....)

Comment: @tcadidot0: I tried changing the table name and the variables. It didn't return error. It ran as if I did no changes at all.

Comment: @tcadidot0: after I changed the table name and variable name, the program only redirected me back to "jenispembayaran.php".

Comment: You mean after you changed them to some non-existent table name etc.? If that's the case, it should return error but instead what happen is seems like the program doesn't even get to the `INSERT ` statement at all. did you write this code from scratch or you copy paste them and edit few lines?

Comment: @tcadidot0: yep. I changed the table and the variables to non-existent names. I copy-pasted and edited several lines (from many tutorials in the internet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried with your code and with my limited PHP knowledge, I couldn't make it work. Also I did find a tutorial similar to your codes but I also couldn't make it work. However, I found another tutorial that works and try to emulate what you're doing with this tutorial instead and I've managed to perform the process that you desire with this code below:

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'mydatabase');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

/* You can set a separate connection file and instead of writing the database connection credentials, 
   just call it using  require_once "config\database.php"; */

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$id_jenisPembayaran = $nama_jenisPembayaran = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Assigning variables with data from input fields
        $id_jenisPembayaran = trim($_POST["id_jenisPembayaran"]);
        $nama_jenisPembayaran = trim($_POST["nama_jenisPembayaran"]);

         // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO jenispembayaran (id_jenisPembayaran, nama_jenisPembayaran) VALUES (?,?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_id_jenisPembayaran, $param_nama_jenisPembayaran);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id_jenisPembayaran = $id_jenisPembayaran;
            $param_nama_jenisPembayaran = $nama_jenisPembayaran;

            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: testing2.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <article class="card">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="id_jenisPembayaran">Kode Jenis Pembayaran:</label>
            <input type="text" name="id_jenisPembayaran" value="<?php echo $id_jenisPembayaran; ?>">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="nama_jenisPembayaran">Nama Jenis Pembayaran:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama_jenisPembayaran" value="<?php echo $nama_jenisPembayaran; ?>">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </article>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

As you can see, the PHP and HTML code are in one single file and honestly I attempted many times just to understand how the flow went because I've manage to post this code but with empty and NULL values. Even though I got this initial code from a tutorial, I had to trim and re-code them to make it work.

This is the source of the tutorial : https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php and I was particularly re-create your codes according to the `create.php` section. Also, please look at the database config section and how every PHP page is calling it to create a connection.

Comment: thank you for your efforts! I tried this and it works. Although, while it manages to post data to my database and redirects back to the form, it also echoes "Something went wrong. Please try again later." at the top left of my form page. Do you know how could I pull this off by separating the php code in a separate file? I tried putting it in **_input-datajenispembayaran.php_** but I got "undefined variable" in both `<input ="text">`. I type the action as: `<form action="./assets/php/input-datajenispembayaran.php">`.

Comment: Honestly, I just learn this PHP because of your question :) . I can try with separating the code into php file but it might take me a while to figure it out. If you're looking for a quick solution, you might want to post a new question with this requirement.

Comment: oh... I see. Again, thank you for your efforts. That means a lot for me. Do you get the error message too? Even though your code manages to post data in your database?

Comment: You mean this message "Something went wrong. Please try again later."? No. On my testing it just redirect back to the page. I've tested on Edge Version 86, Chrome Version 86, Firefox Version 81 and Internet Explorer Version 11, all behave the same.

Comment: Yep. I modified `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_id_jenisPembayaran, $param_nama_jenisPembayaran);` into `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $param_id_jenisPembayaran, $param_nama_jenisPembayaran);` since "id_jenisPembayaran" is an int. That couldn't be the issue, could it?

Comment: I've tried that and didn't receive the error message. Would you mind to post a new question and copy the code that you're working with? Once you've post it, just leave a comment here and I'll be able to find the question. Thanks ;)

Comment: Sure! Thanks a bunch, bro. I'll comment you once I've posted it.

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64493170/html-form-succeeds-to-do-its-job-but-theres-an-error-message-saying-that-somet?noredirect=1#comment114039363_64493170

Comment: I see the question is already being marked as duplicate. Does the [linked duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param) resolve your issue?

Comment: I've tried them, but to no avail. Now I got **Object not found** too.

Comment: I've added the **object not found** issue in the question.